# Getting a file version number in the [Registry] section

Tags: registry, inno-setup, pascal

I am creating an installer for a visual studio project using inno setup. I am getting an error for

```
"Parameter ValueData has invalid value"
```

for this code:

```
[Code]
function GetVersion(AppVersion: String): String;
var
  Version: String;
  CharIndex: integer;
  c: char;
begin  
for CharIndex := 1 to Length(AppVersion) do begin
    c := AppVersion[CharIndex];
    if (c <> '.') then
    Version := Version + c;
end;
Result := Version;
end;

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "MyCompany\Product"; ValueType: DWORD ; ValueName: "Version" ;     ValueData: GetVersion({#MyAppVersion}); Flags: uninsdeletekey;
```

I have versioning like this "1.0.0.3, 1.0.0.4, etc". So this program removes . and concatenates all of them to form a number and should pass back to write to registry. So, I can check this registry value and uninstall or update the previous version. I heard someone saying inno would upgrade automcatically, but I create icons with their name with version number. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `{#MyAppVersion]` may be the problem, but you didn't provide it. (The default is `AppVersion`, without the `My` prefix.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is because to call a function as a parameter in the main sections of InnoSetup, you need to use the {code:} construct.
Here's an example that worked for me:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\MyCompany\Product"; ValueType: DWORD ; ValueName: "Version" ;     ValueData: {code:GetVersion|{#MyAppVersion}}; Flags: uninsdeletekey;
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Ken White said, your constant is "broken" which makes the entire string literal invalid.
Even then, you ValueData is still just `GetVersion(WhateverMyAppVersionIs)` instead if the result of that function.
For that, use a `{code:}` constant to call GetVersion.