# Inno Setup comma error

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I have GetVersion function in [Code] that returns a string like this "1004", "1003", etc.

I created this function to check the registry value for lowest version numbers and uninstall them.

Here is a snippet of the code it is giving error point to StrtoInt conversion line stating

```
Comma (,) expected
```

Here is the snippet:

```
function DoesOldVersionsExist(): Boolean;
var
  AppVersion: integer;
  mstr: string;
  VersionInstalled: cardinal;
begin
  AppVersion := StrToInt(GetVersion({#MyAppVersion}), 0);
...
```

after that line I'm simple comparing the values and return true or false. Much Appreciated.

This is what error message says:

```
Line 55
Column 40.
Comma (,) expected
```

Thanks Deanna but unfortunately that is the error message pointing to this :

```
AppVersion := StrToInt(GetVersion({#MyAppVersion}), 0);
                                     ^
```

Here is the GetVersion function:

```
function GetVersion(AppVersion: String): String;
var
  Version: String;
  CharIndex: integer;
  c: char;
begin  
for CharIndex := 1 to Length(AppVersion) do begin
    c := AppVersion[CharIndex];
    if (c <> '.') then
      Version := Version + c;
end;
Result := Version;
end;
```

Comment: It looks like you have too many closing parentheses.

Comment: When you get an error message, try posting that too as it normally gives a clue as to what the problem is.

Comment: Nice, I changed it still no luck. I will edit my question Thanks.

Comment: As with your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667820/inno-setup-pascal-scripting), you've not told us what the MyAppVErsion define is. That is critical to both the questions as it's being used exactly as is in all the situations. You need to make sure it is "clean" of special characters and quoted as required for it to be used as a literal in the code/script.  
Until we know what that value is, all we're doing is guessing.

Comment: #define MyAppVersion GetFileVersion("Release\myFile.dll")
the version look like this "1.0.0.3"

Comment: Have you even tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't just have Inno Setup constants in code like this, you have to use [`ExpandConstant()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant):

```
AppVersion := StrToInt(GetVersion(ExpandConstant('{#MyAppVersion}')), 0);
```

Comment: That is not a constant. It is a 'magic word' (probably not the official term) recognized by the Inno Setup pre-processor (ISPP).

Answer (score 0):

You have not given us enough information to give a definite answer, but I think that the situation is as follows.

You have defined some constant called `MyAppVersion` which you let the ISPP (the Inno Setup pre-processor) substitute. Now, you have not told us what type this variable is, and you have not told us what the signature of `GetVersion` is (in particular, what type of argument does it expect?). However, *if* these types are strings, you need to write

```
StrToInt(GetVersion('{#MyAppVersion}'), 0);
```

in order to obtain, say,

```
StrToInt(GetVersion('Some string, this is!'), 0);
```

instead of

```
StrToInt(GetVersion(Some string, this is!), 0);
```

which is malformed (indeed, to such an extent that it hurts my eyes to look at it).

Comment: Just added the getversion function. It returns a string.